# gitlab-ci.yaml `config contains unknown keys: rules` when trying to use rules

Tags: gitlab-ci

I've pasted the example for rules in my gitlab-ci.yaml (from https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules):

```
job:
  script: "echo Hello, Rules!"
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH == "master"'
      when: always
    - if: '$VAR =~ /pattern/'
      when: manual
    - when: on_success
```

But I get

```
Error: jobs:job config contains unknown keys: rules
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature is currently only available on gitlab.com.

Check the version of the instance you use and select the corresponding gitlab docs (in the header bar of the gitlab docs pages) eg https://docs.gitlab.com/12.2/ee/ci/yaml/README.html.

Answer (score 0):

The “rules” were introduced in GitLab 12.3. Check your version. Go to❓(question mark next to the account image) / Help.
There you will find the version you are currently using.